# Expectation for PDF

Tags: self-study, expected-value, joint-distribution

I have this PDF:

$$
f(x, y)=\begin{cases} 4xy & \text{} 0<x, y<1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} & \end{cases}
$$

Sample solutions has given that:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x \ 4xy \,dx dy \
$$
should be used to calculate $E(X)$ but why are the integral values from $0$ to $1$ for $x$ and $y$ and not $0$ to $\infty$ for $x$ given that $0<x$ and $-\infty$ to $1$ for $y$ given that $y < 1$?

Comment: The notation $0<x,y<1$ should be understood as "both $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$".

Comment: Technically the expectation *always* involves an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for both variables.  But when it's known that the integrand is zero outside some region $A$, the integral often is written in the form $\iint_A\cdots.$ The expression $\int_0^1\int_0^1\cdots$ is a special case of this where $A=[0,1]\times[0,1].$

Comment: @winperikle Ah, it is supposed to be one single inequality and not two inequalities? The comma is separating the $x$ and $y$ characters and not to represent two different inequalities, correct?

Comment: @Appleguy Yes, both inequalities ($>0$ and $<1$) apply to $x$ and $y$. It can be a bit confusing but it is common to write it this way. If $x$ and $y$ were ranging over different intervals we would expect a notation that clearly emphasizes it, like $0 < x < +\infty, -\infty < y < 1 $ for example.

Comment: When in doubt about the notation for a distribution function, you can usually determine the intended interpretation by checking the axioms: in particular, when you interpret the inequalities as meaning $-\infty\lt y\lt 1,$ is $f$ always non-negative? If $0\lt x\lt \infty,$ does $f$ integrate to unity?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem here is that the notation $0<x,y<1$ is intended to mean that both $x$ and $y$ are between zero and one ---i.e., formally, we have the support:

$$0<x<1 \quad \quad \quad 0<y<1.$$

You can see that this must be true from the fact that your alternative interpretation leads to a "density" function that is negative over much of its range (i.e., it would not be a valid density function under your interpretation).